# Програмирование под Линукс. Ликбез новичка.

Tags: linux, книги

Доброе утро Уважаемые!

Собственно интересует разработка ***прикладных программ*** под Линукс. Сразу оговорюсь - интересует нетолько разработка графических интерфейсов - т.е. под QT либо GTK - но об разработке под Линукс в целом. И с нуля. Интересует все аспекты. Что-то вроде Петцольда для Линукс.

Какую литературу или ресурсы можете рекомендовать для изучения?

**UPD**: Что я подразумеваю под ***прикладная программа*** ? Рабочее место оператора магазина/аптеки/банка, работника предприятия. Т.е. ничего такого связанного с системой.

В моем случае - поставили задачу реализовать приложение по автоматизации процесса работы фирмы среднего уровня - вся бизнес логика уже есть. Т.е. дело за мылым - освоить навыки 
разработки.

**UPD2**: Что хочу узнать, с точки зрения програмиста, и главное где узнать, как делаются в Линуксе следующие вещи:

1. **потоки** - так как приложение будет использовать ресурсоемкие по времени вычисления и задачи, то лучше всего использовать потоки;
2. **сетевые протоколы** - POP3/SMTP, FTP, HTTP/SOAP - разработка и использование. Последнее можно отдельным пунктом, но скорей всего весь пункт - это возможности/расширения языка програмирование;
3. **Базы данных** - скорей всего тоже расширение языка, но все-же не плохо знать как  используется БД в разработке линуксовых приложений;
4. **Системные сервисы** - ибо есть очень много фоновых задач, которые удобно реализовать только сервисами;
5. **Развертывание** - думаю что тут всем понятно - незнакомая среда, непривычные действия - хотелось бы узнать как без попоболи развертывать готовое приложение клиенту;
6. и последнее но одно из самых главных - **Графический интерфейс** - знаю что под Линукс есть две самых главных гуи-тулкита - QT и GTK - но хотелось бы знать насколько сложно создавать богатые графические пользовательские интерфейсы - для особенно циничных скажу что не мы придумываем дизайн а клиент и ему паралельно как это будет реализовано, главное видеть то что ему нужно и как хочет он. 
    Под ***богатые графические пользовательские интерфейсы*** имеется в виду... хотя смотрите у любого разработчика виджетов ([вот](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx), [вот](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/) и [вот](http://devexpress.com/Subscriptions/VCL/) для примера). Я и не говорю чтоб все было готово, на блюдечке с каемочкой, доступно школолопрогеру-мышкофапу, интересует **возможность** и **способы** разработки такого уровня гуи.

Надеюсь что меня поняли.

Comment: Страшный вопрос. Сравнивать сложное winapi (Петцольд с него начинал, win32api было позже), с простыми вызовами POSIX... Конечно, если без всяких QT-GTK на C писать под X'ы, то да. Иначе -- задачи несравнимые по сложности.

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под *прикладными программами* ? Ну, или приведите примеры *системных* (которые Вас не интересуют).

И, извините за безграмотность, что такого написано в двухтомнике Петцольда  (правда не читал), аналоги чего Вы хотите изучить в Линукс ?

Comment: Рабочее место (клиент) на машине с Линуксом ?

Comment: да.. а что это уровня фантастики?

Comment: Нет, просто непривычно. 

Сейчас тенденция делать WEB приложения, т.е. рабочее место в браузере, данные на серверах.

Comment: увы иногда веб не самое хорошее решение...

Comment: @dreadangel, неплохо Вы проапдейтили вопрос. Надеюсь он будет популярен. Картинки по ссылкам (вот, вот ...) впечатляют.

-- 

Лично я попробовал бы делать такие в SmartGWT, а браузер и tomcat с jаvaServlets запустил локально.

Приложение в целом я бы монолитным не делал, поэтому вопрос с потоками во главу угла не ставил. Вообще, по своей изначальной философии, \*nix это клей, которым мы соединяем небольшие блоки  разной формы.

Для связи компонент приложения наряду с сокетами и FIFO, советую обратить внимание на псевдотерминалы (pty). Это я про то, что Вы не прописали *к рассмотрению*

Comment: Так чего же вы хотите конкретно? Всё о Линуксе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Джон Фуско.  [Linux. Руководство программиста.](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5560388/)

Описание -

> Данное руководство позволит вам
> освоить обширный перечень инструментов
> с открытым исходным кодом, доступных
> для GNU/Linux. Автор книги, Джон
> Фуско, подробно и доступно описывает
> наиболее полезные из них, используя
> наглядные краткие примеры, которые
> легко видоизменять и использовать на
> практике. Начав с самых основ -
> загрузки, построения и установки, - вы
> узнаете, как распределены инструменты
> с открытым кодом и как найти
> оптимальное решение для той или иной
> задачи, углубите свои знания о ядре
> Linux и способах взаимодействия ОС с
> программным обеспечением. Изложение
> теоретической информации в книге
> ориентировано на последующее
> практическое применение. Освоив ее, вы
> сможете пользоваться самыми
> продвинутыми инструментами, применяя
> их для разработки собственных
> приложений, а также для увеличения
> производительности ПО и его отладки.

Comment: Хорошая книга, но не для новичка.

Comment: ИМХО, разжёвано всё - дальше некуда,:) но подразумевается, что Linux читатель всё же знает. Ну, если уж совсем просто - тогда серия - "Для чайников" - "Программирование ..." "С ..." С ++..."

Answer (score 3):

Если интересует написание на С, то вполне подойдет книга *Н.Метью, Р.Стоунса "Основы программирования в Linux"* - именно "с нуля", все разжевано ;)

Comment: Самое то, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Не новая книжка (2004 г.), но мне понравилась. Довольно много и толково про взаимодействие программ на Си с системой (файлы, оглавления, tty, сигналы, процессы, потоки, сокеты, System V IPC).

Брюс Моли. Unix/Linux: теория и практика программирования.

оригинальное название - Bruce Molay. Unix/Linux Programming.

Answer (score -2):

С учетом вышеописанной задачи, вам нужно смотреть в сторону Java EE. Смысл вам копаться в низкоуровневом программировании, если вам нужно решать бизнес-задачи?

Comment: ну вот почему на все вопросы о разработке приложений под Линукс сразу опираются в ответах "пользуй Жаву".
Все равно что .NET под винду - я не спорю Жава очень неплоха - особенно в качестве серверной части, но в качестве декстопа?

Comment: Отвечающие так по-видимому изучили java'у. И им хочется, чтобы и другие её изучали, "чтоб жизнь мёдом не казалась"А вообеще есть правило "программы под линукс никому не нужны. Что означает: есть некоторые линуксоспецифичные вещи, их без нужды использовать не надо. А так нижний уровень -- POSIX,  который много кто поддерживает, про qt-gtk и говорить не стоит.

Comment: @dreadangel, а какой GUI Вы видите у себя на Linux десктопе ? Какие-нибудь окошки на питоне ? 

Не пробовал, но думаю можно красиво наваять.

Comment: @avp Окошек на питоне в линух не так уж и мало. В составе дистрибутива. Впервые такое дело увидел году в 2001-2002. Конфигуратор fetchmail'а. Сейчас много больше.

Comment: Вы меня наверное неправильно поняли. Я имел ввиду Java Platform, Enterprise Edition - это целый стек технологий и для клиента и для сервера. Для клиента можно использовать JSF (JavaServer Faces)j, Java Server Pages, Adobe Flex.

Если нужно все-таки под десктоп, то могу посоветовать Qt